# Photoshop CC does not detect AMD Radeon 7770 Card

Tags: graphics, adobe-photoshop

Here's a descriptive image of everything I can show:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvjZs.jpg

I've got an AMD Radeon 7770HD GHz edition graphics card, along with Integrated Intel HD graphics. I'm also running dual monitors, however I use photoshop on the monitor that uses the AMD graphics card. The second monitor uses my integrated graphics.

When I launch photoshop, I get a message saying 3D could not be used as I do not have enough video ram, yet the AMD Radeon 7770HD has PLENTY of ram, photoshop CC requires 500MB while this card has at least 2GB worth of video ram.

The main problem I have with not being able to use the graphics card, is that if a document gets too big while I'm working on it, it will usually crash the program eventually while I'm in the middle of working on something.

If the document is fairly small (< 1024x768), it's fine. Any larger, it crashes.
The sniffer program does not seem to be able to find my graphics card for some reason,
yet I just updated my CCC (catalyst control center) with completely new 2013 December drivers for my card.

What's going on?

Comment: superuser is probably the better place to ask this, because it's not really a programming problem. Just for debugging purposes, what happens if you disable the integrated Intel graphics and run single display on the AMD?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this question is off topic for this site, although not for its sister site Super User. I've requested a moderator migrate the question, so don't feel the need to repost it there; it should end up there before long.